# Изменить отображение карусели при уменьшении экрана Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Не могу разобраться с небольшой проблемой. Как исправить отображение аватаров блока с правильными отступами от текста на мобильных устройствах?
Вот как всё выглядит на "десктопе":

[image: dt]

А вот так на мобильных устройствах (+ при активном втором блоке - первый сдвигается вверх):

[image: mbl]

Как сделать так, чтобы при отображении на мобильных устройствах аватары пользователей были в ряд и не заходили на текст?

HTML и CSS прикрепил к вопросу:

```css
#quote-carousel {
    padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-control {
    background: none;
    color: #CACACA;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    text-shadow: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators {
    right: 50%;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: -19px;
}

#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 4px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 50px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators .active {
    background: #333333;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border-color: #12b5cb;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-inner {
    min-height: 250px;
}

.item blockquote {
    border-left: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.item blockquote p:before {
    font-family: 'Fontawesome';
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
        <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel">
        <!-- Bottom Carousel Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><img class="img-responsive " src="img/carou.jpg" alt="photo">
            </li>
            <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="1"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/carou.jpg" alt="photo">
            </li>
            <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="2"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/carou.jpg" alt="photo">
            </li>
          </ol>
          <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
          <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
          <!-- Quote 1 -->
            <div class="item active">
              <blockquote>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                  <small>Lorem ipsum</small>
                </div>
              </div>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
          <!-- Quote 2 -->
            <div class="item">
              <blockquote>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                  <small>Lorem ipsum</small>
                </div>
              </div>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
          <!-- Quote 3 -->
            <div class="item">
              <blockquote>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                  <small>Lorem ipsum</small>
                </div>
               </div>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Carousel Buttons Next/Prev -->
          <a data-slide="prev" href="#quote-carousel" class="left carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
          <a data-slide="next" href="#quote-carousel" class="right carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Картинки-индикаторы заходят на текст не только на мобильных устройствах, но и на больших мониторах, просто вы этого не замечаете, так как текст короткий.

Индикаторы bootstrap имеют position=absolute и специально "наползают на контент". Таков их дизайн по умолчанию.

Чтобы исправить положение потребуется убрать абсолютное позиционирование (сделать position=static) и переместить блок индикаторов в конец разметки карусели (в разметке html, чтобы они располагались под текстом)

Посмотрите пример кода:

```css
#quote-carousel .carousel-control {
  background: none;
  color: #CACACA;
  text-shadow: none;
}

#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators {
  position: static;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
}

#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 50px;
  opacity: 0.4;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators .active {
  background: #333333;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-color: #12b5cb;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 250px;
}

.item blockquote {
  border-left: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel">
    <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
    <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
      <!-- Quote 1 -->
      <div class="item active">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <small>Lorem ipsum</small>
      </div>
      <!-- Quote 2 -->
      <div class="item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <small>Lorem ipsum</small>
      </div>
      <!-- Quote 3 -->
      <div class="item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <small>Lorem ipsum</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
        <img class="img-responsive " src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="photo">
      </li>
      <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="1">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="photo">
      </li>
      <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="2">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="photo">
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Также учтите:

1. Ваши индикаторы слишком большие для мобильных устройств, поэтому они физически не помещаются в 1 строку и переносятся.
2. Используйте @media, чтобы увеличить их размер на больших экранах, а на малых поставьте размер поменьше. Тогда они будут помещаться в одну строку
3. Скорее всего вы будете вставлять вашу карусель в контейнер или в колонку, поэтому, возможно, отступ от границы каждого элемента карусели будет излишним
4. Уточните момент с минимальной высотой inner-carousel (вы ставите min-height 250px). Если у Вас будет две карусели в соседних колонках и в одной будет значительно больше текста чем в другой, то они будут выглядеть неконсистентно. Возможно, лучше поставить фиксированную высоту.

Это не единственный вариант решения. Вы, например, можете создать собственные индикаторы за границей карусели и привязать на них переключение слайдов, используя события карусели для синхронизации с выбранным индикатором.

Пример:

```
$(this._thumbnails).on('click', function (event) {
        var targetSlide = $(event.currentTarget).attr('data-slide');
        $(me._carousel).carousel(+targetSlide);

        event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
        if (event.stopPropagation)
            event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(this._carousel).on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event) {
        var nextSlide = $(event.relatedTarget).index();

        params.currentSlide = nextSlide;

        $(me._thumbnails).removeClass('active');
        $(me._thumbnails[nextSlide]).addClass('active');
    });
```